Force synchronous processing
I'm coming from a PowerShell background, and at the moment trying to get my head around Swift Concurrency. My first project as it relates to concurrency is a utility to en mass transcribe audio files, and I am banging my head on some basics.
What I am trying to do here is simply get a list of the audio files, then loop through them displaying the one being worked on in the UI, and use a simple timer to simulate the transcription work for now. I found [this][1] that I thought would allow me to use a typical asyncAfter timer but it is not working.
My expectation is that the UI shows the current file name, then after a time the console shows the same while the UI shows the next file name, but the UI is showing only the last file name, and all the writes to console suggest that basically every timer is running in parallel.
In a perfect world I would LIKE to transcribe everything in parallel, but that's another problem, it seems like SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest doesn't support this. Indeed, even just in sequence has given me problems, but I am not even 100% sure I AM doing it in sequence, so I am trying to get any head around forcing that, thus the failed code here.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fileName: String?
    @State private var files: [URL] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("\(fileName ?? "-")")
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            files = getFiles()
            processFiles()
        }
    }
    
    
    private func getFiles() -> [URL] {
        do {
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let path = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Voice Memos").absoluteURL
            
            let contents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: path, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
            
            let files = (contents.filter {$0.pathExtension == "m4a"}).sorted { url1, url2 in
                url1.path > url2.path
            }
            
            return files
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return []
        }
    }
    
    private func processFiles() {
        for file in files {
            Task {
                await processFile(file)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func processFile(_ url: URL) async {
        fileName = url.lastPathComponent
        let seconds = Double.random(in: 10.0...20.0)
        Task.synchronous {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
                print("\(url.lastPathComponent) \(seconds)")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Task where Failure == Error {
    /// Performs an async task in a sync context.
    ///
    /// - Note: This function blocks the thread until the given operation is finished. The caller is responsible for managing multithreading.
    static func synchronous(priority: TaskPriority? = nil, operation: @escaping @Sendable () async throws -> Success) {
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        Task(priority: priority) {
            defer { semaphore.signal() }
            return try await operation()
        }

        semaphore.wait()
    }
}

EDIT: I also tried
let duration: UInt64 = 2_000_000_000 /* 2 seconds */
var seconds: UInt64 { duration/1_000_000_000 }
Task.synchronous { try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration) }

as the timer function, and that just hangs.

You shouldn't combine async/await and GCD (dispatch groups, dispatch semaphores etc). Because you have an unstructured concurrency Task in the for loop, the tasks can all run in parallel. You could move the for loop inside the task.

Please do not mix DispatchQueues and DispatchSemaphores with Swift Concurrency. Among other things, you should put try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration) directly inside processFile, without wrapping it inside a DispatchQueue or Task.synchronous (this extension should not exist in the first place).

Yeah, that second approach was desperation, to be sure. I just don't know enough yet to recognise mistakes. But that's all part of learning.

The files loop your create 4 task run independently, they are not run in a sequence. So the fileName get set to last file's name immendietly.
for file in files {
    Task {
        await processFile(file)
    }
}

Also you should not mix Semaphore with async await. Here might be a refactor for your code, also I use String for simplicity:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fileName: String?
    @State private var files: [String] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("\(fileName ?? "-")")
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            files = getFiles()
            Task {
                await processFiles()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private func getFiles() -> [String] {
        ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    }
    
    private func processFiles() async {
        for file in files {
            await processFile(file)
        }
    }
    
    private func processFile(_ url: String) async {
        fileName = url
        let seconds = Double.random(in: 10.0...20.0)
        await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
                continuation.resume()
                print("\(url) \(seconds)")
            }
        }
    }
}


Woot! Thanks! Now to implement this approach with actual files, do some reading on continuations so I understand WHY it works, and then see if it helps with transcription.

Happy coding :D

Well, I learned something. But sadly it doesn't address the problem with batch transcription. I would have thought that was a very common use case, so Apple would make sure it works. But there aren't even that many questions about it, and certainly no answers. There's a question here that got no response at all. :(
But, learning more about Swift Concurrency is still a valuable outcome.

So you want batching transcription like 3 files in same time?

Well, I have 1000 on the phone, so I would like to do more like 20 at a time. Getting the files out of Voice Memos sucks too. It's so weird that one at a time works, but not batch. Weirdly, they process out of order as well. Super odd. I may start another thread on that topic, and hope it gets more traction than the guy asking last year.

You should ask another question about batching transcription. This question might let people think more about a question of concurrency

Yeah, will do that today. Just figuring out it was a concurrency issue was an achievement. I just ran it again, this time actually reporting the error, and it throws No Speech detected on all but the last one. Feels like that has to be a crumb to follow.

Your title says that you want to “force synchronous processing”. I would suggest that this is not really the case. You just want to avoid running the requests in parallel. You want to run them sequentially, but still asynchronously.
The term “synchronous” means something very specific (namely, something that blocks the calling thread), which you do not want to do (either here, or in general).

So, if you want to run them one-at-a-time, just use Swift concurrency. Once you excise the code of GCD API, you can just remain within Swift concurrency, it is much simpler:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fileName: String?
    @State private var files: [URL] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("\(fileName ?? "-")")
        }
        .padding()
        .task {
            do {
                files = try getFiles()
                try await processFiles()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    private func getFiles() throws -> [URL] {
        let documentsURL = URL.documentsDirectory
        let folder = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Voice Memos")

        return try FileManager.default
            .contentsOfDirectory(at: folder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
            .filter { $0.pathExtension.lowercased() == "m4a" }
            .sorted { $0.path < $1.path }
    }

    private func processFiles() async throws {
        for file in files {
            fileName = url.lastPathComponent
            try await processFile(file)
        }

        fileName = "Done"
    }

    private func processFile(_ url: URL) async throws {
        let seconds = Double.random(in: 10...20)
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(seconds))
        print("\(url.lastPathComponent) \(seconds)")
    }
}

If I add some OSSignposter instrumentation in processFile and then profile the app in Instruments, I can see that they are processed one at a time (despite calling async API):

It is important to note:

No Task {…} inside the for loop.
That is an anti-pattern at the best of times (introducing unnecessary unstructured concurrency). If you did want to run them in parallel, you would use a task group, not a for loop with a nested Task {…}.
But, you explicitly do not want parallelism here, so introducing Task {…} is a step in the wrong direction.

No semaphores.
You cannot use semaphores to manage dependencies between Swift concurrency contexts)

No GCD API.
When using Swift concurrency, you generally want to avoid mixing that with GCD API.



If you want to perform speech recognition, that recognizeText API emits a series of values asynchronously. The analog in Swift concurrency is an AsyncSequence. And the concrete asynchronous sequence implementation is an AsyncStream. So we can make a Swift concurrency wrapper for the Speech framework API:
extension SFSpeechRecognizer {
    func results(with request: SFSpeechRecognitionRequest) -> AsyncThrowingStream<SFSpeechRecognitionResult, Error> {
        AsyncThrowingStream { continuation in
            let task = recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in
                if let error {
                    continuation.finish(throwing: error)
                } else if let result {
                    continuation.yield(result)

                    if result.isFinal {
                        continuation.finish()
                    }
                }
            }

            continuation.onTermination = { state in
                if case .cancelled = state {
                    task.cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func result(with request: SFSpeechRecognitionRequest) async throws -> SFSpeechRecognitionResult {
        request.shouldReportPartialResults = false
        guard let finalResult = try await results(with: request).first(where: \.isFinal) else {
            throw SpeechError.noResult
        }

        return finalResult
    }
}

enum SpeechError: Error {
    case noRecognizer
    case noResult
}

Now, if you are new to Swift concurrency, this might look a little confusing. But the point is that you can replace you processFile with something like:
private func processFile(_ url: URL) async throws {
    guard let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
        throw SpeechError.noRecognizer
    }

    let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: url)
    request.addsPunctuation = true

    let string = try await recognizer.result(with: request)
        .bestTranscription.formattedString

    let destinationUrl = url.deletingPathExtension().appendingPathExtension("txt")
    let data = Data(string.utf8)
    try data.write(to: destinationUrl)

    // Alternatively, if you want to see the results as it is going on:
    //
    // request.shouldReportPartialResults = true
    //
    // for try await result in recognizer.results(with: request) {
    //     print(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
    // }
}

